# angular routerlink redirect to 404

Tags: html, angular, angular-ui-router, http-status-code-404

I have a problem with routerlinks in angular. I use routerlinks to redirect to the next page in my application.

If I start my applicaton with ng serve everything works fine. If I build my application with ng build --prod routerlinks return in some cases a 404.

The exact problem:
I am using a routeroutlet to display the different components. If I click on a routerlink which is in a component that is displayed in the routeroutlet I get a 404. If I use a routerlink that is in my component.html outside of the routeroutlet everything works fine.

That is my routeroutlet

```
<div class="">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

That is my routerlink

```
              <a [routerLink]="['overview']" [queryParams]="{categorie:'Shopping',subcategorie:'topcategorie'}"
                 class="btn btn-primary searchbutton">suchen</a>
```

and that are my routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [

  { path: 'overview/:categorie/:subcategorie', component: OverviewComponent },
  { path: 'overview', component: OverviewComponent },
  { path: 'overview/:brand', component: OverviewComponent },
  { path: 'overview/:product', component: OverviewComponent },
  { path: 'coupons', component: CouponComponent },
  { path: 'impressum', component: ImpressumComponent },
  { path: 'datenschutz', component: DatenschutzComponent },
  { path: 'details/:id', component: ProductDetailsComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: LandingpageComponent },
  { path: '', component: LandingpageComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Are you trying to navigate from `home` path? I think you should change your routerlink as `/overview`

Comment: hasnt helped. this is my code             <li><a [routerLink]="['/overview']" [queryParams]="{categorie:'Shopping',subcategorie:'Büromaterial'}">Büromaterial</a></li>